# Flutter App Cloned with Nfc App Logo when launching via Ndef intent

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, nfc, ndef

I want to launch my Flutter Android App automatically, after an Ndef Tag has been discovered. I'm using an Intent filter to achieve this.

All works fine, apart that when launched via the Ndef Tag, the App has an Nfc App Icon.
Also, if the app was already opened manually before, it will have the App open twice:
a) The manually opened one with the correct logo
b) The Ndef Tag launched one

Screenshot with two instances of the app:

[image]

To exclude any side effects, I did a new Flutter project from scratch and only did the following changes in ...\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:

Added this right after the <manifest> tag:

```xml
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
```

And after the existing

```xml
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

I added this filter to launch the app:

```xml
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="developer.android.com" android:pathPrefix="/test" />
   </intent-filter>
```

The Nfc Tag only has one record of type Uri, with the content `https://developer.android.com/test`

How can I avoid the app clone, and just always open the same App instance with the correct App logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :-)

Andrew pointed me in the right direction.

I had to change `launchMode` in ...\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:

```yaml
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Andrew's link to the docs above helped me getting started.

And this link gives the overall pig picture, how Android tasks and activities work: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#TaskLaunchModes)

Answer (score 0):

To rely on the basic intent nfc functionality you need to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` option to the `Activity` with the NFC intent filter in the Manifest.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode)

> the "standard" and "singleTop" modes differ from each other in just one respect: Every time there's a new intent for a "standard" activity, a new instance of the class is created to respond to that intent. Each instance handles a single intent. Similarly, a new instance of a "singleTop" activity may also be created to handle a new intent. However, if the target task already has an existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, that instance will receive the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new instance is not created

As `standard` is the default `launchmode` then a new instance of the Activity is created when the NFC is scanned every time, hence multiple instances.

With `singletop` it will re-use one that is at the top of the stack **BUT** you will have to handle the processing the data in the `onNewIntent` method as well as where you are processing it now.

Using the method does have the downside that your App with be paused and resumed to receive the NFC data, so your App has to pause and resume correctly. It is generally better to use one of the Foreground NFC methods like [enableReaderMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) instead of the basic intent methods, for Flutter there are various flutter packages to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Andrew. The default new project in Flutter already had `android:launchMode="singeTop"` set. I guess this prevents already the creation of multiple new instances with each new scan. (I only get max 2 instances. See screenshot above)

My fundamental question is: When the normal app with the correct logo is closed or in the background, Android always opens the app with the Nfc logo. Why?

Comment: My Native Android Application has a TECH_DISCOVERED intent filter but a second instance is never started, so I don't know why other than `launchmode`, all I can suggest is you have a look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/nfc/NfcDispatcher.java as this is the code that does the launching to figure out why.