# Background NFC opens duplicate react native app on Android

Tags: android, react-native, nfc, mifare, react-native-nfc-manager

I am using react-native-nfc-manager. When I scan nfc in the background, my app is opened and nfc is handled but I can see in the multitasking that two apps have opened, when with the nfc native handler icon and the other with my app handler.
Because of this behavior of the app is weird. Mutiple success popups would appear and multiple navigation would occur. Seems like changing something on one app triggers action on the other app. below is the android manifest I use to open background tags. On IOS the flow is working perfect. For reference we are using the NFC NTAG216, and I have already enabled forgroundEnable mode in the nodemodules nfcManager.java. Also the behaviour is only odd when the app is in the background when scanning tag.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="nfc-frontend-testing.crunchyapps.com" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="nfc-frontend-testing.crunchyapps.com/nfc/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_filter" />

    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.holguinmedia.contactapp"
              android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.holguinmedia.contactapp"
              android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

[In the photo as it can be seen, the left app is our app and the right app is the system native app handler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaBrY.jpg)

I have tried disabling lines in the manifest I thought were the reason for this, but they would just disable the whole nfc background opening functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter App Cloned with Nfc App Logo when launching via Ndef intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75482235/flutter-app-cloned-with-nfc-app-logo-when-launching-via-ndef-intent)

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrew, it did solve my problem yes.. I have no idea how but wow to you...

Comment: Hi! @AbdullahKhalil, I am using react-native-nfc-manager but it's not working in Android but in iOS, its working fine. Can you help to resolve it?